# Matlab regex ${numberFun($4)} - Undefined function 'numberFun' for input arguments of type 'char'

Tags: regex, matlab

I read that in Matlab it is possible to include a function call inside a regex transformation like this `$1double$2[${doubleTextNumber($4)}]`, assuming 1, 2, 3 to be some regex groups, and 4 to be a purely numeric group. The exact thing I want to do is to catch all arrays consisting of the type creal_T, replace the type with double and double the length of the array.

```
codeText = "typedef struct {
      double tolRob;
      creal_T Mt2o[704];
      creal_T Ho2o[704];
      creal_T Ht2t[704];
      creal_T Zo2t[704];
      creal_T Ztd[64];
 } testType;"
```

So, I want the struct above to become:

```
typedef struct {
      double tolRob;
      double Mt2o[1408];
      double Ho2o[1408];
      double Ht2t[1408];
      double Zo2t[1408];
      double Ztd[128];
 } SpdEstType;
```

In Matlab I have made a function to convert a number to text and double it:

```
function [doubleValue] = doubleTextNumber(inputNumber)
    doubleValue =  string(str2double(inputNumber)*2.0);
end
```

I also have a regex that I expect would find the number in each declaration and feed it to the function:

```
resultString = regexprep(
codeText,
'(?m)^(\W*)creal_T(\s*\w*)(\[([^\]]*\d+)\])',
"$1double$2[${doubleTextNumber($4)}]");
```

However, as I run this peace of code, Matlab gives me the following error msg:

```
Error using regexprep
Evaluation of 'doubleTextNumber($4)' failed:

Undefined function 'doubleTextNumber' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

As far as I understand, I have made the method do conversion from char, and expect it also to accept this value from my regex. I have tested that it works when I input '704' or "704" directly, and also that the regex works appart from this insertion.

Why does not Matlab find the function from my regex? (they are in the same m  file)

Comment: Should it not be covered by this line from the table of Replacement Operators? 
`${cmd} | Output returned when MATLAB executes the command, cmd`

Comment: Ok, I see, [this page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/dynamic-regular-expressions.html) has got some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I had 3 issues with my original approach:

1. In order for `regexprep()` to recognize my function, it had to be moved to its own m-file. Simply calling a method from inside the same file did not work.
2. I was using https://regex101.com/ to edit the search expression, but even though it seemed to be selecting the number inside the brackets, group 4 did not get populated by `regexprep()` in Matlab. A new version did work, and populated group 3 with the numbers I wanted: `(?m)^(\W*)creal_T(\s*\w*).([^\]]*\d*)\]`
3. I also added more conversion options to my multiplication method in case the input was a combination of numbers and char arrays.

The final version of my regex call becomes:

```
resultString = regexprep(
    codeText,
    '(?m)^(\W*)creal_T(\s*\w*).([^\]]*\d*)\]',
    "$1double$2[${multiplyTextNumbers($3,2)}]");
```

where multiplyTextNumbers() is defined in its own m file as

```
function [productText] = multiplyTextNumbers(inputFactorText1,inputFactorText2)
%MULTIPLY This method takes numbers as input, and acepts either string,
%char or double or any combination of the three. Returns a string with the
%resulting product. 
    if (isstring(inputFactorText1) || ischar(inputFactorText1))
        inputFactor1 = str2double(inputFactorText1);
    else
        inputFactor1 = inputFactorText1;
    end

    if (isstring(inputFactorText2) || ischar(inputFactorText2))
        inputFactor2 = str2double(inputFactorText2);
    else
        inputFactor2 = inputFactorText2;
    end

    productText =  sprintf('%d',inputFactor1*inputFactor2);
end
```

Hope this can be helpefull to others facing similar issues.